# Run a login script without startup folder

Tags: windows, script, boot, batch-file

So I have to run a login script when User X logs on. I put that script (.bat) in the startup folder and it works fine. However, I also have to disable the explorer shell and once I do that the startup script no longer runs because the startup folder is part of explorer. Is there another way to run a startup script on logon for User X without the startup folder??

I tried doing everything listed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324803

But if you make a folder in system32 there's no way to share it, the computer won't let you, so this tutorial can't possibly be correct

Comment: If you're disabling the explorer.exe shell, are you using an alternate shell for a user interface?

Comment: No, I want no interface. All the computer is supposed to do is open internet explorer on logon and the user can't do or use anything else

Comment: You share the FINAL folder (scripts), if I read that correctly

Comment: I did, it won't let you share the system32 file or anything in it

Comment: I just shared the folder, no issues. What is showing up when you try?

Comment: What OS are you using, and how do you have sharing configured?  I can share the system32 folder perfectly happily.  Try using the command line command net share instead of the GUI.  (But see my answer: there's a better way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gpedit.msc to assign a logon script using local group policy.  You can put group policy logon scripts anywhere you like, so long as you specify the full path.

If you're in a domain, and the users in question are logging in using domain accounts, use domain group policy instead of local group policy.

Comment: Just to be clear: in this scenario, the logon script doesn't need to be on a share at all.  Specify the local path, e.g., c:\scripts\logon.cmd.

Comment: Okay, and what is gpedit.msc? I remember trying to run that before and I couldn't find it on my computer. (Windows XP). I just found it on this computer (Windows 7, I'll look again on XP)

Comment: Okay, I got it to work! Thanks =D Damn, the tutorials online really really need to learn this method, this method even lets you assign logoff scripts and is totally hidden to the User (unlike putting a script in the Startup folder)